# PHP foreach succesfull loop reassign a variable in the beginning of loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a loop where it query's mysql for a search but the search will change by the end of the query.
What i found out with my coding is which i did not now is that i can't reassign a variable to a new search query, or not correctly anyways.

I have added echo's to see what it's doing.

Lets say John is assigned to $preg_split

What i am trying to do is to match a character with a database if one the first characters in the database for example J matches then assign the second character from $pre_split which is o so $char would be jo

So the variable $char in the beginning should be updated with jo

Instead for some reason which i'm sure that i just did not write my code correct is that it echo's o an not jo..

So i'm a bit puzzled why its the second character and not the first.

```
$NG_implode = implode("", $preg_split);

$NG_split = str_split($NG_implode, 1);
$i = '0';
$ia = '1';
$ib = '0';
$ic = '1';
$char = $NG_split[$ib];


foreach ($NG_split as $char)
{

    $NG_select_like = "SELECT word FROM checklist_filter WHERE word LIKE '".$char."%'";
    $NG_query = mysql_query($NG_select_like) or die(mysql_error());
    $NG_row = mysql_fetch_row($NG_query);
    $chars = str_split($char, 1);
    $row = str_split($NG_row[0], 1);
        if ($chars[$i] == $row[$i])
        {

            $char = $char.$NG_split[$ia];

            $ia++;
            $i++;
            if ($char == $NG_row[0]){break;}
            }else{$ib++; $char = $NG_split[$ib];}

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$char` gets set to the next value of `$NG_split` in every new iteration of the `foreach` loop , so the value you're assigning to `$char` inside your `foreach` loop won't be there anymore next time. Can't you simply do this?

```
<?php
$str = "John";
$len = strlen($str);

$arr = array();
$i = 0;
while($i < $len) { 
    $arr[] = substr($str,0,$len-$i);
    $i++;
} 

var_dump($arr);
?>
```

Now if you iterate over `$arr` you should be able to build the queries you're interested in. There's probably an even more efficient way to get the results you're looking for using a regular expression in MySQL but it would help if you could share a bit more about your use case for this.

Comment: Hiya Daan, thanks for the explanation, the understanding of foreach has made things allot more understandable. I will now try and utilize the while loop and see how i can get that to work. I'll post back with the final results to share the info. Thanks :)

Comment: i came to the conclusion with your example and for my situation a do while works perfect, thank you very much for the help                              $x = '0';
 echo 'step-'.$x.'<br>';
 do {
  echo 'step-'.$x.'<br>';
  $x = ($x + '1');
  echo 'step-'.$x.'<br>';
  echo 'end step<br>';
  }while($x <= '5');